# No module named 'pymongo' despite installation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When I run 
`import pymongo`
I obtain 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'`
despite 
`!pip install pymongo`
returning
`Requirement already up-to-date: pymongo in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (3.8.0)`

I'm using python notebook with Python version 3.7.1 and pymongo version 3.8.0

I tried unistal and re-install pymongo, with no result.

None of the suggestions I've seen on similar questions seem to work (or I was unable to understand how to apply them).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `pymongo` got installed in /usr/local/lib/**python2.7**, but you mentioned that you're running iPython with the Python 3.7 interpreter.

I'm guessing you have two or more Python installations on your system (2.7 and 3.7) and 2.7 is the default.

An immediate fix for your problem is to install `pymongo` for the Python 3.7 interpreter.  The command depends on where you have Python 3.7 installed, but it would be something like

```sh
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pip install pymongo
```

But you should really, *really* be using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to separate your Python installations.  Use something like [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) to create a virtual environment, install `pymongo` inside the environment, and configure your notebook to use the environment instead of your global Python installation.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much @zachdj Your guess was correct and your suggestion solved the problem.